# tailwindcss not working in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, class

I am using tailwindcss for the first time and especially in a react app. I followed the documentation, read some articles and watched some videos. I have my react-app running but tailwindcss classes do not reflect on the application. I have restarted the project from scratch severally but I still face the same issue.
Here is my package.json

[image]

Comment: Did you import tailwind on your code?

Comment: The build:css command create a `output.css` file, but that file must be imported on your page or it won't have any effect

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean by import tailwind. Do you mean importing the  @tailwind base, ...components and... utilities, because I did. And I also have the output.css imported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this issue by reinstalling autoprefixer@^9.8.6. This video pointed out rightly https://youtu.be/v6Sy6VP2yOc

Comment: This solution does not work for me.

Answer (score 48):

I had to upgrade the react-scripts

```
npm i react-scripts@latest
```

Comment: This is very helpful if you are using node 17 and using legacy options to use create-react-app

Answer (score 14):

What I have done is

- Updating version of tailwindcss,postcss,autoprefixer and react-scripts to the latest version.
- Replacing tailwind.config content with

```
    content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./index.html"],
```

Answer (score 14):

Try

```
import styles from "./index.css"
```

In your .js/.jsx where you want to use the Tailwindcss

your index.css must contain

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gp_ this was all I needed to solve my problem.

I should also mention that this import statement should be in _app.js if using NextJS.

Comment: Thanks, It helps me a lot. I forgot to add that index.css file

Answer (score 11):

This is happening because of installing tailwind in Devdependencies. Try reinstalling without -D

Comment: Exactly! That's how I managed to solve this issue, by simply installing without `-D` .

Comment: you shouldn't need to but ok, it worked

Answer (score 8):

For react applications, there are dedicated tailwind CSS docs. In `tailwind.config.js` inside `module.exports` changed the content from `content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"]` to this

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

this fixed my issue

Comment: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app refer docs for react application

Answer (score 8):

step 1 -

follow all steps from [tailwind official steps](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app)

step 2 -

```
npm install tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer@^9.8.6
```

step 3 (for typescript no require)-

```
npm install react-scripts@latest
```

step 4 -

```
 npx tailwindcss init -p
```

step 5 -

run your react application

Answer (score 4):

Installing `postcss` and `autoprefixer` to dev dependencies along with tailwindcss worked for me

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer 
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

Answer (score 4):

If your are using craco and webpack 5, you need to replace postcss with postcssOptions in your `craco.config.js`, example:

```js
// craco.config.js
module.exports = {
    style: {
        // why use postcssOptions? -> https://github.com/dilanx/craco/issues/353
        postcssOptions: {
            plugins: [
                require('tailwindcss'),
                require('autoprefixer'),
            ],
        },
    },
}
```

For the details please check this issue: https://github.com/dilanx/craco/issues/353
[image]

Answer (score 2):

do

```
npm i tailwindcss postcss-cli autoprefixer@^9.8.6
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I have followed all the steps to install tailwind in my project using [this.](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app)
And then tried to fix the issue by:

1. `npm install tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer@^9.8.6`
2. `npm install react-scripts@latest`

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to solve this issue by installing these into the `dependencies`:

```
npm install tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
```

Answer (score 0):

all the configurations from https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app tailwind docs didn't work for me, then I just went to

tailwind.config file

then changed the content to link to just one tsx file

```
  content: [
    "./src/page/attendee/Home.tsx",
  ],
```

and it worked for all of my components

Answer (score 0):

I went through most of the suggestions and obviously none were going to work if i had a spelling mistake,

It was a simple **s** missing from **module.exports**, please check your **spelling**

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons for this. Try all the steps mentioned below:

Follow these steps to install TailwindCSS with Vite (React):

> npm create vite@latest your-project-name -- --template react

> cd your-project-name

> npm install tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer

> npx tailwindcss init -p

Inside the tailwind.config.js file, within the **'content: []'** section, add:

> ```
> "./index.html",     
> "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
> ```

6. Now, within your 'index.css', clear all the code and enter the.
   following:

   > @tailwind base; 
   > @tailwind components; 
   > @tailwind utilities;
7. Try updating your React scripts:

   > npm i react-scripts@latest

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the server needs to be restarted after installing and setting up Tailwind CSS to get reflacted. Try canceling the current process and starting it again.